# Looking for a word or term that means "artistic", "stylish", and "creative"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've only come up with "left-brained" but I wondered if there was something else.

Update: Turns out I should be using 'right-brained'.

Comment: In your title, you already gave a good option. "Creative" can also mean artistic and stylish.

Comment: True. I'm trying to conjure the picture of someone who is an artist and someone who is a designer....

Comment: Did you mean "right-brained"? Describing someone by their brain functionality is more clinical than complimentary.

Comment: Describing people as "left" or "right" brained is kinda out of date.

Comment: @Cascabel I know, that's why I'm looking for a better term :)

Comment: @WeatherVane No, these terms are going back to the idea that analytical people are "right-brained" and creative people are "left-brained". Out of date, as Casabel mentioned, but I am not sure of a more encompassing word.

Comment: I meant it is the [**other way round**](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/right-brainleft-brain-right-2017082512222). *Those who are right-brained are supposed to be intuitive and creative free thinkers ... left-brained people tend to be more quantitative and analytical*. So, did you mean "right-brained"?

Comment: @WeatherVane is right as to the assignment of  sidedness, but it is not supported clinically AFAIK. It was a theory, and pretty much debunked in the last century. People think differently, and use different parts of their brain.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, you're right. I always assumed that book was for analytical people to become more artistic.

Comment: You still need a sample sentence demonstrating use of the word per the SWR tag. We need to see how it works in context, and POS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***designer***

> a person who ***imagines*** how something could be made and ***draws plans*** for it:

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designer)

Designers are creative, stylish, and artistic.

"Designer"  would include any number of disciplines; from Graphics, to Electronics; from Kitchen cooks to Geneticists.

***imagineer***

> A person who devises and implements a new or highly imaginative concept or technology, in particular one who devises the attractions in Walt Disney theme parks.

[-Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/imagineer)

Comment: Another writer once said they are _engineers_ >.

Comment: I am definitely not going for engineer. But maybe 'imaginative' would work.

Comment: In Español, we have _creativo_...

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I've decided to use "imaginative" which gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why the words you use do not suit your needs. One combination would be "*Surprisingly original*" though not one word. Your criteria for choosing is too open.
Art is to describe that which is already there; people in sculpture or portraits etc.
Style is to reflect what others are already doing.
Creative is by definition that which creates.

Comment: Style to me is fashion. Creative means 'designer'. Artistic mean 'painter, musician', etc.